# Overwrite typescript package types

Tags: typescript, types, module

I have a package I've published (@hakit/core) and this provides an interface (can convert to type if need be) called SupportedServices.

What I'm after is a way for the user of this package to be able to "redefine/replace" this entire interface as this is a package that automates the usage of the home assistant instance, everyone's setup is very different.

I've provided a script that re-generates the whole interface based on the current instance.

However I'm struggling to replace the whole type, I can extend, but updating/replacing obviously doesn't work with typescript.

Is there alternate options I could try here?

```
import { ServiceFunction, ServiceFunctionTypes } from "@hakit/core";

declare module "@hakit/core" {
  export interface SupportedServices<T extends ServiceFunctionTypes = "target"> {
    light: {
      // Turn on one or more lights and adjust properties of the light, even when they are turned on already.
      turnOn: ServiceFunction<
        T,
        {
          // Duration it takes to get to next state.
          color_name: number;
        }
      >;
    };
  };
}
```

This is what I tried, but when I use other functions that use this interface internally, they still point to the original turnOn method (obviously)

Is there something I can provide at the package level, to somehow replace the whole type if it's available?, something like

`CustomSupportedServices` and then SupportedServices would be something like:

```
interface DefaultSupportedServices = { ... }
// somehow check if CustomSupportedServices exists and use that else DefaultSuportedServices?
type SupportedServices = ...
```

I don't think it's possible to check if an interface/type exists or not, but any suggestions would be great!

EDIT:

Just updating my question with the answer provided below directly tied to my question:

In my package:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
export interface CustomServicesContainer<T extends ServiceFunctionTypes = "target"> {
  
}

export type SupportedServices<T extends ServiceFunctionTypes = "target"> = | [keyof CustomServicesContainer<T>] extends [never] ? DefaultServices<T> : CustomServicesContainer<T>
```

Then on the user side, if that interface is extended and isn't empty, it will simply use that interface instead:

```
import { ServiceFunction, ServiceFunctionTypes } from "@hakit/core";

declare module "@hakit/core" {
  export interface CustomServicesContainer<T extends ServiceFunctionTypes = "target"> {
    computer: {
      // Turn on one or more lights and adjust properties of the light, even when they are turned on already.
      turnOn: ServiceFunction<
        T,
        {
          // Duration it takes to get to next state.
          apples: number;
        }
      >;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check for if interface exists, but you can check if it's empty

```
type BaseT = { a: number }
type DefaultT = { a: 123 }

interface EmptyCase<T extends BaseT = DefaultT> { }
interface FilledCase<T extends BaseT = DefaultT> { }
interface Fallback<T extends BaseT = DefaultT> {
    fallback: T
}

// a case when it's empty
type FallbackIfEmpty<T extends BaseT = DefaultT> =
    | [keyof EmptyCase<T>] extends [never] ? Fallback<T> : EmptyCase<T>
type A = keyof FallbackIfEmpty
//   ^?
// type A = "fallback"


// a case when it's not empty
interface FilledCase<T> { t: T }
type FallbackIfEmpty2<T extends BaseT = DefaultT> =
    | [keyof FilledCase<T>] extends [never] ? Fallback<T> : FilledCase<T>
type B = keyof FallbackIfEmpty2
//   ^?
// type B = "t"
```